# FixUp-esque Collection for NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework

I'm working on getting started with NHibernate on a large scale project (have worked with it in small-scale before), and am digging into the issue of **managing relationships**... specifically, what best practices are out there for doing so?

Example: The classic: you have a Blog and Comments, the blog points to (0-n) comments, each comment in the collection points back to the blog {0,1}.

Out-of-the box it seems it's up to you to not shoot yourself in the foot (by mis-matching the child object relationships, for example).  We're hoping for a better solution to build upon...

One option I've found is making the collection private and providing accessor/mutation methods for it.  The **fixup** can then be done in those methods.

But I'm wondering if a better solution is out there-- something like a "**FixupCollection**" (used in the [Entity Framework's **POCO template**](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/pages/feature-ctp-walkthrough-poco-templates-for-the-entity-framework.aspx))

Also, **Ayende** mentions a FixupCollection of his own ([ADO.Net Entity Framework Round II post](http://ayende.com/Blog/2006/06/24/ADONetEntityFrameworkRoundII.aspx), can't find any code though): "I wrote my own collection classes for NHibernate that will do the fixups for the relationships".

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very old post (2006) and I think Ayende's talking about [EntitySet / EntityRef / EntityList](http://www.ayende.com/projects/nhibernate-query-analyzer/generics.aspx) which he wrote back when .Net 2.0 was new (2005). Here are some posts about it:

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2005/09/30/NHibernateOnNet20PartI.aspx
- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2005/10/01/NHibernateOnNet20PartIII.aspx
- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2005/10/01/NHibernateOnNet20PartIVTheSucess.aspx
- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2005/10/07/BugFixInNHibernateGenerics.aspx
- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2005/12/23/NHibernateGenericsEntityListUpdate.aspx

I don't think this is maintained anymore, [here's the latest code](http://svn.berlios.de/viewvc/nqa/NHibernate.Generics/?pathrev=171) I was able to find.

Comment: Great! I did look for that but failed to find it, good call on the svn repository, thanks! :)

That answers part of the question-but I'm still wondering what most people out there do for dealing with this issue... if the answer is "by hand" that's cool too

Comment: Personally yes I do it by hand.